# akka http binding error

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am using `akka http` and earlier when I used to run my `Boot.scala` file it used to run fine, but after a month or so I ran my `Boot.scala` today, but its throwing some exception which I can't understand, someone please help. Error message is:

[image]
This is my `build.sbt file`:

[image]

This is my `Boot.scala` file:

[image]

and finally my `rest file`:-
[image]

Comment: Could you please post full stack trace? and what kind of error you're getting?

Comment: @Atiq, I just updated my complete error log i am getting, plz check

Comment: plz update your akka-stream version to the latest and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine I think the problem is with your dependencies please try updating your Scala version as well as your Akka library versions it should solve the problem.